# Changing multiple variables in a command using arrays

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I have an inline command that works on the DOFRI (Database, Object, Field, Record, Index) Model. I would like to iterate and change multiple parameters in the command simultaneously using multiple arrays

In line DOFRI Command

```
"updatesysdb 11 15 88 545112 0"
```

I would like to change the Record (545112) and Index (0) parameters using my list of parameters through each iteration. Everything else ("updatesysdb 11 15 88") can remain the same.

"updatesysdb 11 15 88 %p %q"

Where %p is each value in my array of Records
Where %q is each value in my array of Indexes

My Array

```
set MMU_Mv_Records=155655 155656 155657 155658
set MMU_Mv_Indexes=1500 900 1100 300
```

Here is what I was able to come up with so far, but cannot get it to print the desired output to test the theory.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set MMU_Mw_Indexes=155655 155656 155657 155658
set MMU_Mw_Values=1500 900 1100 300
for %%p in (%MMU_Mw_Indexes%) do (
for %%q in (%MMU_Mw_Values%) do (
echo updatesysdb 11 15 88 %%p %%q
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500> nul))
```

Desired Output

```
"updatesysdb 11 15 88 155655 1500" 
"updatesysdb 11 15 88 155656 900"
"updatesysdb 11 15 88 155657 1100" 
"updatesysdb 11 15 88 155658 300"
```

So I've figured out how to change %p and %q at the same time, but the loop results in 8 lines instead of just 4. I think it's because it's how the loop is configured where the outer loop prints, then the inner loop. I think I'm close, but not sure how to reduce the duplicate looping.

Thanks Magoo for the response! I modified it a tad to help with scaling

```
@echo off   
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "MMU_REC=551255 551256 551257"
set "MMU_IDX=0 1 4"
(for /L %%I in (1,1,3) do call :RunTest %%I) & exit /B
:RunTest
for /F "tokens=%1" %%J in ("%MMU_REC%") do set "V_REC=%%J"
for /F "tokens=%1" %%J in ("%MMU_IDX%") do set "V_IDX=%%J"
echo updatesysdb 11 15 88 %V_REC% %V_IDX%
REM ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500> nul) 
timeout /t 2 /nobreak>nul
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Where did you enable delayed expansion? Also, the last string on your bottom line should be `!array{%%v}!`. Or, the command string should probably be, ```updatesysdb 11 15 88 !array[%%v]! !array{%%v}!```.

Comment: Oh, and `set i+=1` & `set s+=1` should be `Set /A i += 1` & `Set /A s += 1` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given clarification,

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "MMU_Mv_Records=155655 155656 155657 155658"
set "MMU_Mv_Indexes=1500 900 1100 300"

FOR %%p IN (%MMU_Mv_Records%) DO (
 SET "p5=Y"
 FOR %%q IN (!MMU_Mv_Indexes!) DO (
  IF DEFINED p5 echo updatesysdb 11 15 88 %%p %%q
  SET "p5="
 )
 SET "MMU_Mv_Indexes=!MMU_Mv_Indexes:* =!"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

For each member of the first list,

- set a flag (p5)
- set `%%q` to the each (remaining) member of the second list in turn
- if the flag is set, `echo` a line with `%%p` and `%%q`
- clear the flag so no more `echo`es take place
- remove the first member of the second list

Comment: Thanks plenty ! This worked like a charm. I went ahead and streamlined it a bit more to allow me to change more parameters if needed as well. Thanks for your patience and resubmit :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `!var!` facility, you need a line

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
```

Normally, this is included directly after the `@echo off` line. By default, extensions are enabled so the `enableextensions` is usually optional (and omitted).

Your code, as it stands, sets up `array[!i!]` and `array[!s!]` (literally) and repeatedly assigns the value from the appropriate list to the variable, so `array[!i!]` will contain the value of the *last item* of the list (rinse and repeat for `array[!s!]`, obviously)

You don't say exactly what your application is, but I'd suggest

```
@echo off
setlocal
:again
if "%1"=="" goto done
echo updatesysdb 11 15 88 %1 %2
shift&shift&goto again
:done
```

and then execute

thisbatch 155655 0 155656 1

to produce the output you suggest.

Note that the number pairs can be repeated as many times as you desire, within reason, or the line

```
call thisbatch 155655 0
```

could also be used, possibly in a loop iterating a list built by other code.

Comment: My apologies, I probably didn't explain myself clearly, and have edited the question for clarity. I am basically looking for a way to change 2 parameters in a fixed string using 2 arrays (%p, %q) through each iteration. The loop to end when it is out of values to read in array %p. No shifts, just a hard return with each iteration as in the desired output provided.